# how do I get a grouped bar chart based on the dataframe I have?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is the data I see

```
    Year    drugs_used      count
0   2012    COCAINE            37
1   2012    FENTANYL            8
2   2012    HEROIN             85
3   2012    HEROIN, COCAINE    36
4   2013    COCAINE            43
5   2013    FENTANYL            6
6   2013    HEROIN            117
7   2013    HEROIN, COCAINE    48
8   2013    HEROIN, FENTANYL    6
```

How can I create a grouped bar chart such that `year` is on X, `count` is on Y and the grouped bars plotted show the `drugs_used`?

Comment: Check this link https://plot.ly/pandas/bar-charts/#pandas-grouped-bar-chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can using `pivot` and `plot`

```
df.pivot(*df).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Such a simple answer for something I have struggled with for hours. Cheers!